# Getting 0 rows returned on query

Tags: sql, sql-server

so let me start will the basic table layout for all tables involved:

**#zip_code_time_zone**

```
+----+----------+-----------+
| id | zip_code | time_zone |
+----+----------+-----------+
|  1 |    00544 |        -1 |
|  2 |    00601 |        -3 |
|  3 |    00602 |         0 |
|  4 |    00603 |        -3 |
|  5 |    00604 |         0 |
+----+----------+-----------+
```

**#pricing_record**

```
+------+---------------+--------------------+
|  id  | location_code | service_center_zip |
+------+---------------+--------------------+
| 7119 | TX725         |              79714 |
| 7121 | TX734         |              75409 |
| 7122 | TX737         |              78019 |
| 7124 | TX742         |              75241 |
| 7126 | TX751         |              77494 |
+------+---------------+--------------------+
```

**#transaction_record**

```
+----+-----------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+
| id | truck_stop_code |   create_date    | gps_verified | central_time |
+----+-----------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | CA428           | 05/01/2015 14:52 |            0 | NULL         |
|  2 | CA343           | 05/01/2015 19:10 |            0 | NULL         |
|  3 | CA223           | 05/01/2015 09:28 |            0 | NULL         |
|  4 | CA721           | 05/01/2015 07:55 |            0 | NULL         |
|  5 | MN336           | 05/01/2015 06:46 |            0 | NULL         |
+----+-----------------+------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

When I was working on this project an issue was noticed with the `create_date` column in `transaction_record`. It needs to be converted to central time, so I wrote an update query, but I have been unable to successfully set the `central_time` column. My query is below:

**query**

```
UPDATE t
SET t.central_time = DATEADD(hour, z.time_zone,CONVERT(DATETIME, t.create_date, 120))
FROM eagle_devel.dbo.zip_code_time_zone z
INNER JOIN eagle_devel.dbo.pricing_record p ON z.zip_code = p.service_center_zip
INNER JOIN eagle_devel.dbo.transaction_record t ON t.truck_stop_code = p.location_code
```

This is what i get when I run the query

```
(0 row(s) affected)
```

**NOTES**

The `time_zone` column in `#zip_code_time_zone` is not the standard UTC it is the difference to calculate to central

I am still working on this as we speak, just looking for some extra assistance to see if someone else can fix it faster than myself.

Comment: It looks like the query you wrote is correct, so it is probably data related. Run the FROM JOIN JOIN as a query to see the results from the query.

Comment: Ok, keep the inner joins (despite the suggestion below: Left join will mess up your wanted result). Test every step of the query:
First the FROM with the first INNER JOIN: More than 1 result: Ok, next step, test the 2 JOIN against each other. Look for a single record which you know which should match, look that up, etc.

P.S. Check for trailing spaces in the data: Add a TRIM around all values (will slow down the query a lot, so usually you would never do that)

Comment: Looking at the sample data posted, there is no match between `zip_code` and `service_center_zip`, hence the first `INNER JOIN` results in `0` rows being returned

Comment: there's more zip code's than that, it's just there for formatting, and display purposes, the zip code table is a national database

Comment: The only arbitrary variable looks to be the `truck_stop_code` joined to the `location_code` (I mean, zip codes are zip codes, right?). Try a simple `SELECT t.central_time FROM eagle_devel.dbo.transaction_record t INNER JOIN eagle_devel.dbo.pricing_record p ON t.truck_stop_code = p.location_code`. Does that give you results?

Comment: yes it does, I get 48,344 rows, which is all of them :)

Comment: Can you update your post with sample data that SHOULD join, but doesn't?   Your issue doesn't look reproducible.   The query looks perfectly fine, which suggests that your data isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this instead with little changes, table you are updating should be in `FROM` clause and then adjust the `JOIN` accordingly

```
UPDATE t
SET t.central_time = DATEADD(hour, z.time_zone,CONVERT(DATETIME, t.create_date, 120))
FROM eagle_devel.dbo.transaction_record t
INNER JOIN eagle_devel.dbo.pricing_record p ON t.truck_stop_code = p.location_code
INNER JOIN eagle_devel.dbo.zip_code_time_zone z ON z.zip_code = p.service_center_zip
```

Comment: `(0 row(s) affected)` Still nothing :/

Comment: Either of the `JOIN` not matching at all. What if you change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: then it returns everything, and that's not what I want either, that shouldn't matter though, because the zip code table is a compiled national database, so it has every single zip code in the country in it

Comment: Strange! check and verify whether you do really have matching records between the tables you are joining. That's the only issue I see.

Comment: Also, try  `TRIMMING` before joining like `LTRIM(RTRIM(z.zip_code))=LTRIM(RTRIM(p.service_center_zip))`